# Java JADE add Cyclic Behaviour

Tags: java, eclipse, agent, agents-jade

How I can add `CyclicBehaviour` when `handleElapsedTimeout()` (timeout) and start again? This is my task for school. I will be very grateful if someone give me a advice.

Here's my code:

```
package test3;

import jade.core.Agent;
import jade.core.behaviours.CyclicBehaviour;
import jade.core.behaviours.OneShotBehaviour;
import jade.core.behaviours.ParallelBehaviour;
import jade.core.behaviours.TickerBehaviour;
import jade.core.behaviours.WakerBehaviour;

public class test3 extends Agent {
    protected void setup(){

        ParallelBehaviour pb = new ParallelBehaviour(ParallelBehaviour.WHEN_ANY);
        pb.addSubBehaviour(new WakerBehaviour(this,5000){
            @Override
            protected void handleElapsedTimeout() {
                System.out.println("timeout");
                myAgent.doDelete();
            }
        });

        /*
        pb.addSubBehaviour(new CyclicBehaviour(this){
            public void action (){
                System.out.println("Cycling");
            }
        }
        );
        */

        pb.addSubBehaviour(new TickerBehaviour(this,100){

        int random;
        @Override
        protected void onTick() {
            random = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.println("random number =  " + random);
            if(random == 5)
            {
            System.out.println("I found it!");
            myAgent.doDelete();
            }                   
        }
    }); 
        addBehaviour(pb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're spelling everything correctly? Typically languages use US English (e.g. `behaviour` -> `behavior`).

Comment: In this case (JADE) it is behaviour. Have used it many times.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the `myAgent.doDelete();` sentence and remove and freshly add in its place a new `TickerBehaviolur(...)` or `CyclicBehaviour(...)`, managing conveniently the control flow of your agent, as appropriate.